# Send email to post author 1 day before his project ends

Tags: hooks

I am running wordpress with a job board and I would like to integrate an automated email notification:

Users post jobs as a custom post type. Freelancers can send proposals within 7 days. When 1 day is remaining, the post author shall receive an "ending soon" email.

The custom post uses an "ending" field to display the remaining time.Here is a code snippet to display the time on the frontend:

```
<?php echo __("Expires in",'ProjectTheme'); ?> <p><?php echo ($closed=="1" ? __('Closed', 'ProjectTheme') : ProjectTheme_prepare_seconds_to_words($ending - current_time('timestamp',0))); ?>
```

I think a cron job can do the work to check if the job is ending in 1 day?!

Not sure what to do next - looking forward to your answers!

And sorry for my bad english ;)

Chris

Comment: Can you explain where do you have the problem? Sending the email? Setting up the cron job? What is the `$ending` variable?

Comment: Thank you for asking! I don´t know how to send the mail. The ending variable is a date (unix timestamp), displaying how many days are left to make a proposal for the job.

Comment: Take a look to [wp_mail() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) and [wp_mail questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-mail). If you still need help implementing it, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I understood how to send mails. But I still need the code to perform a check when the project ends. For example:

if "project ends in 1 day" then send mail to post author